# access folders and get files 

Tags: matlab

I start with Matlab and would like to know how could I access to a folder and get contents to access files and read them.
I have a variable in workspace tmpfolder that is equal to 'path to folder' but I don't find how could I make dir(tmpfolder) and get files, browse any file content to get a string value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an image file in jpeg format in another folder named `myimage` and a text file called `mytext`, use:

```
prefix_image='myimage';
prefix_data='mytext';
fileformat='.jpg';
dataformat='.txt';
folder='C:\Users\khaled\Documents\MATLAB\';

image = imread(strcat(folder,prefix_image,fileformat));

data=textread(strcat(folder,prefix_data,fileformat),'%f');
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start with [`dir()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html) and [`fopen()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/fopen.html).

More generally, try starting at the beginning: [*Working with Files and Folders*](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_env/br5rtt_.html).